# $(TargetPath) not evalutated on loading macro?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-macros

I've a file `custom.props` where I define some macro to be used within the project. In the example, I've this:

```
<VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS>$(TargetPath) /noload /nosave /noexc /noft</VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS>
```

When I load the project, and I look at Properties, Debugging, Command Arguments, I can access to that macro `VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS`. But the string is evalutated as `/noload /nosave /noexc /noft`

Basically, `$(TargetPath)` is not evaluted. In my case, that path point to a DLL, so it should be somethings like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VstPlugins\Plug\vst2\Win32\bin\MyPlug.dll" /noload /nosave /noexc /noft
```

But its empty. How could I fix it? Also tried this:

```
<VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS>"$(TargetPath)" /noload /nosave /noexc /noft</VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS>
```

but the result is:

```
"" /noload /nosave /noexc /noft
```

Comment: I have a similar layout and it works for me. Try to copy-paste contents on common into your props file perhaps to see if it changes anything?

Comment: Except that I don't use it for Debugging / Command Arguments. Try to use that macro in pre/post build step to see if it's evaluated. It might be that in Debugging it works differently.

Answer (score 1):

> $(TargetPath) not evalutated on loading macro?

To resolve this issue you should import your `custom.props` file **after** importing file `Microsoft.Cpp.targets`:

```
   <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
   <Import Project="Custom.props" />
```

That because the value of [Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(v=vs.100).aspx) set by the file `Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets`:

```
  <Target Name="SetUserMacroEnvironmentVariables" 
          Condition="'@(BuildMacro)' != '' and '$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'">

    <SetEnv Condition="'%(BuildMacro.EnvironmentVariable)' == 'true'"
        Name   ="@(BuildMacro)"
        Value  ="%(BuildMacro.Value)"
        Prefix ="false">
      <Output TaskParameter="OutputEnvironmentVariable" PropertyName="%(BuildMacro.Identity)"/>
    </SetEnv>

  </Target>
```

And the file `Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets` is imported by the file `Microsoft.Cpp.targets`:

```
 <Import Condition="'$(_Redirect)' != 'true'" Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets" />
```

So **if you call the some macro in your custom file before importing the file `Microsoft.Cpp.targets`, MSBuild could not get the value of macro.**

You can get those `.targets` files at following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets
```

**To verify the custom value** of `VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS`, I add a simple target to output that value. So you project file should be like:

```
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />

  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>

  <Import Project="Custom.props" />

  <Target Name="TestByCustom" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="$(VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS)"></Message>
  </Target>
```

After build completed, we could get the value of `$(TargetPath)`:

[image]

My custom.props file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
   <VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS>"$(TargetPath)" /noload /nosave /noexc /noft</VST2_32_COMMAND_ARGS>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've checked. Its already in this way. This add `IPlugEffects.props` https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/blob/iplugquake/Examples/IPlugEffect/projects/IPlugEffect-vst2.vcxproj#L81 . Which adds `custom.props`: https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/blob/iplugquake/Examples/IPlugEffect/projects/IPlugEffect.props#L4 So it should be correct...

Comment: @markzzz, I have checked your project file, it seems you add `IPlugEffects.props` after importing `Microsoft.Cpp.props` rather than `Microsoft.Cpp.targets`, the last few lines of the project file. https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/blob/18f8273a78f8d77a381f4df7104c814f5b97d335/Examples/IPlugEffect/projects/IPlugEffect-vst2.vcxproj#L447

Comment: I see. I'll try to change it and I'll let you know! Thanks for now. You will get +1 if it will work ;)

Comment: @markzzz, you are always welcome, if it not work for you. Please let me know for free.

Comment: I'm not really able to config it, due to how that TargetPath is build I think. The correct one shouild be: `C:\Dropbox\Development\C++\wdl-ol\Plugins\IPlug2Test\build-win\vst2\Win32\bin\IPlug2Test.dll`

Comment: If I place `$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets` immediatly after `$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props`, it becomes `C:\Dropbox\Development\C++\wdl-ol\Plugins\IPlug2Test\Debug\IPlug2Test-vst2.dll`, which is wrong and different

Comment: So it seems if works only if I place after any `IPlug2Test.props`, but at this point I've the previous problem :(

Comment: Anyone? :) Do you get what  I'm trying to saying? :)